# Microsoft Graph: Requests to voice calls endpoint return 500 UnknownError without message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I created an app for Microsoft Teams which provides a bot and makes requests to the Graph API to get some user details.
All is working fine so far. The app is trusted and I can work with the Graph API.

I set up the bot to support voice calls and when I call the bot, I do get a POST request with all information.
However when I want to [work with this call, e.g. reject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/call-reject?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) it immediateley, the request to Microsoft Graph API fails with status code 500: UnknownError.

This is my testcode:

```
async RejectIncomingCall(id) {
  const client = await getAuthenticatedClient(this.token);

  try {
    return await client.api(`/app/calls/${id}/reject`).version('beta').post('');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error rejecting call!', e);
  }
}
```

I have no information what's wrong.
I can reproduce this behavior using the Graph Explorer when I try to [get a call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http):
[image]

So in fact all requests to the call API seem to be failing.
Any idea, what I did wrong?
Did I missunderstood something or is the beta api at this point just not working?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an unknown error because of the kind of request you're trying to make.
If you wish to reject a call, you'll have to make a `POST` request not a `GET` request.
Refer to this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/call-reject?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request) for more clear reference.
In graph explorer change the request type from `GET` to `POST`. Check if it works. If not, let me know.

Comment: The screenshot was not the rejection, it was the [Get call method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). I see my description and the screenshot was confusing, I improved it. But the point is, I cannot make any requests to the calls api at all, it always fails with 500, no matter if I try to get a call, reject a call or accept a call.